# Text is not showing up when making screen smaller

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a responsive website and let a h3 show up when i make the screen smaller but it is not showing up. Here is my code:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1486px) 
{ 

.resptekst
{
    visibility: visible;
}

}

.resptekst
{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="tekst">
                    <h3 class="resptekst">Contact</h3>
</div>
```

The text needs to show up when i make the screen smaller, when screen is big enough text should be not visible.

Comment: Based upon your question, you have the class properties *reversed* in the CSS. The hidden property should be *inside* the media query.

Comment: You must mark an answer as correct if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

`@media only screen and (max-width: 1486px)`

Means "target everything smaller than 1486px"

So change your css to:

```
.resptekst
{
    visibility: visible;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1486px) 
{ 
   .resptekst
   {
       visibility: hidden;
   }
}
```

Comment: But the OP wants the text to be shown when making the window **smaller**: *let a h3 show up when i make the screen smaller*

Comment: You're right, just said it as explanation. I have changed it

Answer (score 0):

change css position

css render top to bottom way

```
.resptekst
{
    visibility: hidden;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1486px) 
{ 

.resptekst
{
    visibility: visible;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the order of the CSS rules. 
Place the general rule before the @media rule, otherwise it will always override it, regardless of screen size.

In CSS, always specify from generic to specific, otherwise the generic rules will override the specific ones.

```css
    /*Generic rule*/
    .resptekst
    {
        visibility: hidden;
    }

    /*small screen specific rule*/
    @media only screen and (max-width: 1486px) 
    { 
    
        .resptekst
        {
            visibility: visible;
        }
    
    }
```

```html
    
    <div class="tekst">
                        <h3 class="resptekst">Contact</h3>
    </div>
```

If you have a large enough display (full HD for example), you can test this snippet by clicking on the `Run code snippet` button and then clicking on the `Full page` button.

Answer (score 0):

Media query should be at last, your css without media query comes first

```css
 .resptekst
{
   visibility: hidden;
}



@media only screen and (max-width: 1486px) 
{ 

.resptekst
{
    visibility: visible;
}

}
```

```html
<div class="tekst">
                    <h3 class="resptekst">Contact</h3>
</div>
```